# Como somar valores por categoria?

Tags: mongodb

Tenho alguns dados estruturados da seguinte forma:

```
"_id" : "",
"filmes" : [ 
    {
        "nome" : "Filme 1",
        "categoria" : "terror",
        "qtd" : 7
    }, 
    {
        "nome" : "Filme 2",
        "categoria" : "comedia",
        "qtd" : 7
    },
    {
        "nome" : "FIlme 3",
        "categoria" : "terror",
        "qtd" : 7
    },
    {
        "nome" : "Filme 4",
        "categoria" : "terror",
        "qtd" : 7
    },
    {
        "nome" : "Filme 5",
        "categoria" : "comedia",
        "qtd" : 7
    },
    {
        "nome" : "Filme 6",
        "categoria" : "romance",
        "qtd" : 7
    },
]
```

Estou tentando desenvolver uma consulta que some os valores por categoria e me traga os dados da seguinte forma (somatória da "qtd" por categoria):

```
"_id" : "",
"livros" : [ 
    {
        "categoria" : "terror",
        "qtd" : 21
    }, 
    {
        "categoria" : "comedia",
        "qtd" : 14
    },
    {
        "categoria" : "romance",
        "qtd" : 7
    },
]
```

Tentei algumas coisas do tipo:

```
db.filmes.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project:
      {
        _id: "$_id",
        totalfilmes: { $sum: "$filmes.qtd" }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

mas não consigo agregar por categoria. Alguém tem alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esse tipo de operação é necessário fazer o agrupamento acompanhado por `$unwind` (desconstrair), que irá desconstruir o array. Vou explicar.

```
db.teste.aggregate([ {$unwind: "$filmes"} ])
```

Irá dar o seguinte resultado:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a68d429f9d74b22f6ac43be"), 
    "filmes" : {
        "nome" : "Filme 1", 
        "categoria" : "terror", 
        "qtd" : 7.0
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a68d429f9d74b22f6ac43be"), 
    "filmes" : {
        "nome" : "Filme 2", 
        "categoria" : "comedia", 
        "qtd" : 7.0
    }
}
...demais itens
```

E então agrupar por *categoria* e não por *id*. O `$unwind` irá permitir acessar cada item do *array*, por isso do `_id` do agrupamento, que é onde indicamos os campos que irão estar inclusos, ficando `_id: "$filmes.categoria"`. Ou seja, acessando a categoria de cada filme.

### Resultado

```
db.filmes.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: "$filmes"
    },
    {
      $group:
      {
        _id: "$filmes.categoria",
        total: {$sum: "$filmes.qtd"}
      }

    }
  ]
)
```